# Is there function similar to wp_upload_bits() that will allow uploading to a specific path?

Tags: filesystem-api

[`wp_upload_bits()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_bits) allows you to put arbitrary binary data into a file, but it selects the path where the file is placed and doesn't allow configuration of this destination besides the basename.

There's always the option of playing with the [Filesystem API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API) directly, but I was wondering if there is a similar function to `wp_upload_bits()` that would wrap the logic for me. Last thing I want is to reinvent the wheel.

It's probably not relevant, but the bits being uploaded are being extracted from image/video metadata. A lot of the functionality is being reworked based on code from [`wp_generate_attachment_metadata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_attachment_metadata).

Comment: Why the default location is not good for you? where would you want to locate the generated file?

Comment: Because the file generated needs to be in the same directory as the AV file being parsed in order to work with some other core WP functions.

Comment: There is the $time parameter that looks like a directory specification, and in any case anything under uploads should be writeable in any way you want so you don't have to use that specific API

Comment: Ah. Good eye. Hadn't realized that time was used to specify a directory under uploads. And yes, I know I don't have to use the Filesystem API, but as much as possible I prefer to let existing WP code handle the work unless existing functionality can't handle what I need.